# Login failing with JSOUP

Tags: java, post, jsoup

I'm trying to login to this website: https://bostad.stockholm.se/Minasidor/login/ (Press button lösenordskonto to get the right login). I've scanned through the html for the form and I found the action url that is triggered after pressing login: https://login001.stockholm.se/siteminderagent/forms/login.fcc
But I have not successfully gotten any cookies back. Am I missing some required POST data? Where can I check for this?

Here is my code:

```
    try {
        //In this url you must login
        //String loginUrl = "https://bostad.stockholm.se/Minasidor/login/";
        String loginUrl = "https://login001.stockholm.se/siteminderagent/forms/login.fcc";


        //First login. Take the cookies
        Connection.Response res = Jsoup
                .connect(loginUrl)
                .data("USER", "user")
                .data("PASSWORD", "pass")
                //.referrer("http://www.google.com")
                .userAgent(
                        "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6")
                .method(Method.POST).timeout(0).execute();

        Map<String, String> loginCookies = res.cookies();

        System.out.println(res.hasCookie(url));}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open up Chrome developer tools, in the console type in `$("input")`.

There you will see all the inputs you need to provide to the server, and you need to include those **HIDDEN FIELDS** as well.